# How to get first in last out using sql and check the missing logs with night shift

Tags: sql, t-sql

```
Biometric logs
---------------------------------------------------------
ID     EMP_BIO_ID   LOG_DATE     LOG_TIME   LOG_TYPE
16979   145         20140205    1653        0 
13880   145         20140206    0606        1    
13963   48          20140212    0505        0    
13964   48          20140212    1821        1
13964   48          20140212    1821        1     
13965   48          20140213    0513        0    
13966   48          20140213    1810        1    
13967   48          20140214    0512        0
13967   48          20140214    0512        0     
13968   48          20140214    1811        1    
20219   48          20140215    0606        1 
20219   48          20140215    0606        1
20219   48          20140215    0606        1   
20221   48          20140217    1810        1    
13972   163         20140203    0605        1
13973   164         20140203    0607        0
13974   165         20140203    1815        1
--------------------------------------------------
```

How can I make a query in SQL Server to extract the data look like this:

```
-------------------------------------------------
EMP_BIO_ID   LOG_DATE    LOG IN    LOG OUT  
145         20140205    1653        0606            
48          20140212    0505        1821      
48          20140213    0513        1810         
48          20140214    0512        1811      
48          20140215    0606        1810   
164         20140203    0607 
165         20140203                1815          
---------------------------------------------
```

- 0 is for TIME IN
- 1 is for TIME OUT

My apologies I'm a newbie in VB.NET.

Comment: You're asking how to write a SQL query and yet all your tags are VB-related. What's up with that? The language used to write your application is irrelevant to the SQL code it executes.

Comment: If you haven't attempted anything for yourself, it's too soon to be posting here. Being new to something just means that you don't know, not that you can't find out. It's your responsibility to at least make an effort and then, if it doesn't work, show us what you've done and explain how it doesn't meet your needs. You should spend some time in the Help Center to learn how this site works, including taking the tour that you ignored when prompted during registration.

Comment: Why do you have duplicates ids?

Answer (score 0):

This is sort of gaps and island problem. You may try below query -

```
SELECT EMP_BIO_ID, LOG_DATE, MIN(LOG_TIME), MAX(LOG_TIME)
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT EMP_BIO_ID, LOG_DATE
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY EMP_BIO_ID, LOG_DATE, LOG_TIME) SEQ1,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY EMP_BIO_ID, LOG_DATE ORDER BY EMP_BIO_ID, LOG_DATE, LOG_TIME) SEQ2
      FROM Biometric)
GROUP BY EMP_BIO_ID, LOG_DATE, SEQ1-SEQ2;
```

Answer (score 0):

You seem to want the next "logout" for each distinct "login".  I would suggest:

```
select li.emp_bio_id, li.log_date, li.log_time as login_time,
       lo.log_time as logout_time;
from (select distinct li.*
      from logs li
      where li.logtype = 0
     ) li outer apply
     (select top (1) lo.*
      from logs lo
      where lo.emp_bio_id = li.emp_bio_id and
            lo.logtype = 1 and
            lo.log_date = li.log_date and
            lo.log_time > li.log_time 
      order by lo.log_date desc, lo.log_time desc;
     ) lo;
```